# ASync CTP stable?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, async-ctp

In our current project we must use Silverlight 4 (our customer cannot distribute SL5 yet). We also use MVVM 4.0.

Because of Silverlight4 we encounter many async handling and we want to prevent 'spaghetti' code when chaining all the async events. We are looking for a framework, like the ASync framework from Microsoft to cope with this 'spaghetti' code.

The issue is that ASync framework is CTP and might have bugs and there is possible API change when this release becomes RTM.

Is the current ASync framework CTP version stable enough to go in production ?

Comment: What “current Async framework CTP” do you mean? The best version with async currently is Visual Studio 2012 RC.

Comment: ASync CTP version 3.0 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9983)

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to use VS 2012 RC? It contains more stable and up-to-date version of async.

Comment: This is just a gut feeling not to use non-RTM tooling...

Comment: But the CTPs are even less stable than the RC. That's why they are called technology previews. If you don't want to use RC, then you shouldn't even think about using CTP.

Comment: But the customer only accepts Silverlight 4 (otherwise he has to push SL5 to all client machines)....

Comment: @svick: you are totally right here. We are now strongly considering using VS2012RC. My only concern is how it affect the build server (MSBUILD) on the TFS 2010 instance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AsyncCTP is quite stable, but moving to Silverlight 5 seems like a better idea.
Also there is no support for Async/Await in Silverlight 4 projects in Visual Studio 2012 (yet?). For developing Silverlight 4 you should either stick with Visual Studio 2010 and AsyncCTP v3 supporting Silverlight 4 or update your project to Silverlight 5 and use [Async Targeting Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29576) for Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: At the end this is solved: we are currently using SL5, with VS2012 and the ASync targeting pack for SL5.